# Get top 5 scores/names from list

Tags: c#, sorting

I am adding a function to keep track of scores for a small game I made.
I want to get the top 5 scores (including name for that score) from a file that contains the scores.

The format of the saved scores is:

> [name]-[score]

The scores and names are stored in 2 lists, which I parse this way:

```
string scores = File.ReadAllText(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TEMP") + "/scores");
string[] splitscores = scores.Split('\n');

foreach (string entry in splitscores)
{
    string replace = entry.Replace("[", "").Replace("]", "");
    string[] splitentry = replace.Split('-');

    if (splitentry.Count() > 1)
    {
        scorenames.Add(splitentry[0]);
        scorelist.Add(Int32.Parse(splitentry[1]));
    }
}
```

Then I retrieve #1 player by using:

```
int indexMax
    = !scorelist.Any() ? -1 :
    scorelist
    .Select((value, index) => new { Value = value, Index = index })
    .Aggregate((a, b) => (a.Value > b.Value) ? a : b)
    .Index;

lblhighscore1.Text = "#1:  " + scorelist[indexMax] + " by " + scorenames[indexMax];
```

How can I set the remaining 4 players assuming this is my scorelist:

```
[broodplank]-[12240]
[flo]-[10944]
[bill]-[11456]
[tony]-[9900]
[benji]-[7562]
```

I've figured I could do a descending sort of the score list, but that wouldn't cover the changes in the indexes of the usernames list, what is the best approach for this?

Comment: Instead of `ReadAllText` / `.Split`, you could start with just `ReadAllLines`.

Answer (score 9):

Best approach? Don't use [parallel collections anti-pattern](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2014/06/03/anti-pattern-parallel-collections/).

Instead of having 2 lists, create a class that can hold both the name and the score together

```
class Score
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public int Score { get; private set; }

    public Score(string name, int score)
    {
        Name = name;
        Score = score;
    }
}
```

and have just one list

```
List<Score> scores = new List<Score>();
```

```
foreach (string entry in splitscores)
{
    string replace = entry.Replace("[", "").Replace("]", "");
    string[] splitentry = replace.Split('-');

    if (splitentry.Count() > 1)
    {
        scores.Add(new Score(splitentry[0], Int32.Parse(splitentry[1]))
    }
}
```

You can easily order by one property and because the whole object will be reordered you'll keep the names in the right order without any additional code:

```
topScores = scores.OrderByDescending(x => x.Score).Take(5);
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to MarcinJuraszeks useful answer, some small things that I came across using his solution which I decided to share.

First problem was with the class which threw me the following error

> 'Score': member names cannot be the same as their enclosing type

Changing the case of "s" fixed it

```
class Score
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public int score { get; private set; }

    public Score(string name, int Score)
    {
        Name = name;
        score = Score;
    }
}
```

And calling the individual values can be done with Linq

```
string numberOne = topScores.Skip(0).First().score
string numberTwo = topScores.Skip(1).First().score
```

and so on